# How to avoid the bold version of the caption of the algorithm

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I am using `algorithm2e` package, but I want to remove **Algorithm 1** in the figure and just say the name in my case as just appear only "The procedure". How we can do that?

```
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
a=1\;
b=2\;
c=2\;
\caption{The procedure}
\label{algo:sj2}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the anaswer by my self thanks all. by adding 
    \NoCaptionOfAlgo 
we can remove the name Algorithm1.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
a=1\;
b=2\;
c=2\;
\NoCaptionOfAlgo
\caption{The procedure}
\label{algo:sj2}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\SetAlCapSty{}` to reset the default `\textbf` styling:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlCapSty{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon

    a=1\;
    b=2\;
    c=2\;

    \caption{The procedure} \label{algo:sj2}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf):

> `\SetAlCapSty{<commandname>}`: sets the command that will be used by `\AlCapSty` to defines tyle of `Algorithm #:` in caption. The argument is a name of a command (without `\`). This command have to take one argument, the text to be formatted. Default is set to: `\SetAlCapSty{textbf}`.